# Black columns in the disparity map when using StereoBM

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to use StereoBM in OpenCV to extract a disparity map from a pair of images. Ignoring the bad quality of the disparity map below, you can see that it has a number of black columns on the left which correspond to the parameter ndisparities. I thought that ndisparities only tells StereoBM how "far" away it can search for a correspondence. What could cause this behaviour? It seems to limit the width of the resulting depth map, but I don't see why.

[image: Disparity map]

You can see the stereo pair [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7MAH.jpg) and my code below. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

```
Mat Limg = imread("left.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat Rimg = imread("right.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat disp(Limg.size(), CV_16SC1), disp8U;
int ndisparities = 512;
StereoBM SBM(StereoBM::BASIC_PRESET, ndisparities , 11);
SBM(Limg, Rimg, disp, CV_16S);

double minVal, maxVal;
minMaxLoc( disp, &minVal, &maxVal );
disp.convertTo( disp8U, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));
imshow("disparity", disp8U)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The disparity map quantifies the longitudinal (epipolar) offset between corresponding pairs of points in the left and right image.

In principle,

```
 disparity := x_l - x_r
```

where `x_l` and `x_r` are the projections on the focal plane of the two cameras of a given point in the space. (Keep in mind that large disparities characterize pixels which are *closer* to the cameras. [A])

---

The parameter `ndisparities` quantifies the *expected* maximum disparity you can have  (assuming you can neglect the min disparity).

Since you are assuming that `ndisparities` is your largest disparity, it holds true

```
    x_l - x_r < ndisparities,
```

i.e.

```
    x_r > x_l - ndisparities
```

therefore, it makes no sense looking for correspondences  with the right image of any pixel in the first `ndisparities` columns of the left image: simply you can't have.

In a sense, the view cone of the right camera starts exactly `ndisparities` columns on the right of view cone of the left camera.

---

**A FIX:**

If you want less *black columns* on the left hand side of the disparity map, you need to be able to assume lower values of  `ndisparities`.

Since `ndisparities`  depends on the distance from the cameras of the closest object (from [A]), either put the cameras further away from the object or put the cameras closer one another.

In your very specific case you have a huge disparity (a lot of work for the stereoBM)!! The 'x' symbol in the foreground shows a disparity comparable with the scale of the image!! I believe you need to put your cameras further away.

Comment: That does make a surprising amount of sense, although it's unintuitive that the field of view would decrease when allowing higher disparities.
The cameras are so close in order to get as detailed a view of the object as possible.

Comment: Hey. Here's a way around. Pad some image on the left of image. Then trim it. ... but soon i realized this post was 2013 one. Too late i think.